# Simplifying complex excel formula with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a macro that is generally slow due to overuse of LOOKUP formulas. I want to insert some VBA variables to speed these up. I am currently working on speeding up the formula below:in Excel:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,Summary!B:B,0)),"n",I2-((I2/LOOKUP(2,1/(I:I<>""),I:I))*VLOOKUP(A2,Summary!$G$10:$H$902,2,FALSE)))
```

in VBA:

```
"=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-9],Summary!C[-8],0)),""n"",RC[-1]-((RC[-1]/LOOKUP(2,1/(C[-1]<>""""),C[-1]))*VLOOKUP(RC[-9],Summary!R10C7:R902C8,2,FALSE)))"
```

The portion I need to replace is `LOOKUP(2,1/(C[-1]<>""""),C[-1])`. All this does is reference the last non empty cell in column I. Right now I have the following code to return the address of the last cell in VBA

```
Sub FormulaTest()
Set lRow = Range("I1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address

End Sub
```

I am trying to figure out how to implement this "lRow" into the VBA code for the formula. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

**EDIT 1
Please see Fernando's comment below. He has the right idea however the solution is still off a bit. Ill try to explain it better in a few comments: First off, The first row is always a title row, the last row is always a sum row, the current tab is the "Sales" tab, and the amount of rows in any given Sales tab will vary (could be I1:I59, could be I:1:I323).

In this example I1 is a row title and I59 is the sum of I2:I58. Rows I2:I58 are dollar amounts. My macro places this formula in J2:J58. This formula takes each row's dollar amount (I2:I58) as a percentage of the total (I59) and multiplies it by an input amount on the Summary tab (the VLOOKUP). This amount is then subtracted proportionately from the dollar value in column I with the J cell showing the result.

I am looking to eliminate the need for the LOOKUP function (selects last non empty cell) within my formula above: LOOKUP(2,1/(C[-1]<>""""),C[-1]).

**EDIT 2
Fernando's solution worked. Thank you all for your input

Comment: Where are you putting these formulas?  "=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-9],Summary!C[-8],0)),""n"",RC[-1]-((RC[-1]/LOOKUP(2,1/(C[-1]<>""""),C[-1]))*VLOOKUP(RC[-9],Summary!R10C7:R902C8,2,FALSE)))"     Just in one column?

Comment: These formulas are placed in column J for any row with cell A matching a corresponding cell on the Summary tab

Comment: Do you really need formulas on your worksheet? You might be better off accomplishing whatever it is you are doing solely in VBA.  Read your range into a variant array; then go through the array to create your results; then write it back to the worksheet.

Comment: Your question says you use INDIRECT, but your example doesn't have INDIRECT in it. You also need to give more information to get the best results from this forum. What does the formula do? How many items in the lookup list? How long is it currently taking to calculate? Moving the logic to VBA might speed it it, but I'm almost certain that if you provide answers to my questions then I could give you a lightning fast formula or an approach using PivotTables that is quicker and simpler than a VBA approach.

Comment: Also, you've only posted part of your code. It's possible that part of your slow speed symptoms are to do with how you are populating the worksheet with these formulas. Are you writing the formula to one cell at a time? You could also radically speed up the formula by using `IFERROR` to replace the need for `IF(ISNA` and you could probably use an array formula to process the entire range at once. But again, you need to further elaborate on what you are trying to do,  what your data layout looks like, and how the rest of your code is structured.

Comment: I added a few comments above - let me know if they help. I have to put a microscope on this macro because it's 15 pages of code and this is a small part of what it does. There are other areas I need to improve but am trying to focus on just the LOOKUP issue for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would return the last non-empty row  in column I

```
with Worksheets("Summary")
lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
end with
```

So your code would be

```
sub testy
dim lRow as long
with Worksheets("Summary")
lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
end with

"=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-9],Summary!C[-8],0)),""n"",RC[-1]-_
((RC[-1]/R"&lRow&"C[-1])*VLOOKUP(RC[-9],Summary!R10C7:R902C8,2,FALSE)))"
```

In your solution you're using `xlCellTypeLastCell`. This is very useful, but it calculates based on `UsedRange`, which may not be what you want. with this, if you have data up to row `n` and then you update the data and now you have less records, the last row with `xlCellTypeLastCell` will still be `n`, so be careful with that.

Comment: I used the following code and it returned Zero for the new LOOKUP value

`IF(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-9],Summary!C[-8],0)),""n"",RC[-1]-((RC[-1]/" & lRow & ")*VLOOKUP(RC[-9],Summary!R10C7:R902C8,2,FALSE)))"`

Comment: try using `"=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-9],Summary!C[-8],0)),""n"",RC[-1]-((RC[-1]/R"&lRow&"C[-1])*VLOOKUP(RC[-9],Summary!R10C7:R902C8,2,FALSE)))"`

Comment: I had to add brackets : `"=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-9],Summary!C[-8],0)),""n"",RC[-1]-((RC[-1]/R[" & lRow & "]C[-1])*VLOOKUP(RC[-9],Summary!R10C7:R902C8,2,FALSE)))"`

Please take a look at my comments above - The formula is returning a cell 2 cells below the one I need. Any idea what might be causing this? I also need to make this an absolute reference

Comment: in RC notation, if you use brackets it is a _relative_ reference, meaning that it will use the cell that's _n_ rows below the one where you are calling the formula. Meanwhile, without brackets it's an _absolute_ reference, meaning that R100, for example, will always reference row number 100, as opposed to R[100], which would be 100 rows directly below where you're calling the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are doing all your work on the active sheet, looking up to a "Summary" sheet:

```
Sub fillCol()

    Dim aRow As Long, bRow As Long

    aRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    bRow = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("J2:J" & aRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-9],Summary!C[-8],0)),""n"",RC[-1]-" _
                       & "((RC[-1]/" & aRow & ")*VLOOKUP(RC[-9],Summary!R10C7:R" & bRow & "C8,2,FALSE)))"

End Sub
```

You made need to change the columns which contain the contiguous range (in order to determine the last row)

Comment: This returns the row number of the cell im looking for:

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,Summary!B:B,0)),"n",I2-((I2/59)*VLOOKUP(A2,Summary!$G$1:$H$10,2,FALSE)))`. I need it to return the address so the formula will use the 59th cell

Comment: That formula has `59` hard coded into it.  If that row won't change just set `aRow = 59`.  Either that or have some other algorithmic way to choose the row number.  But your formula is basically a really complicated way to choose a hard-coded row address.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear.  If you can phrase it in a way that doesn't require us to interpret what your data may be based on your nested formula then we can give a more specific response.  Are you trying to get the last row of your summary sheet?  that's what `bRow` is in my solution.

Comment: Please see Fernando's comment above. He has the right idea however the solution is still off a bit. Ill try to explain it better in a few comments: First off, The first row is always a title row, the last row is always a sum row, the current tab is the "Sales" tab, and the amount of rows in any given Sales tab will vary (could be I1:I59, could be I:1:I323).

Comment: In this example I1 is a row title and I59 is the sum of I2:I58. Rows I2:I58 are dollar amounts. My macro places this formula in J2:J58. This formula takes each rows dollar amount (I2:I58) as a percentage of the total (I59) and multiplies it by an input amount on the Summary tab (the VLOOKUP). This amount is then subtracted proportionately from the corresponding value in column I with the J cell showing the result.

Comment: I am looking to eliminate the need for the LOOKUP function within my formula above: `LOOKUP(2,1/(C[-1]<>""""),C[-1]` by dynamically referencing the last cell (I59 in this case). Let me know if this clears things up.